# Duplicate line numbers

Tags: line-numbering

I'm having trouble with duplicate line numbers see below.

[image]

These are the lines that appear to be the problem.

```
   %\authors{Author One\correspondingauthor{Author One, 
    % American Meteorological Society, 
    % 45 Beacon St., Boston, MA 02108.}
% and Author Two\thanks{Current affiliation: American Meteorological Society, 
    % 45 Beacon St., Boston, MA 02108.}}

\authors{Bruce Davison\correspondingauthor{Bruce Davison, Environment Canada, 11 Innovation Blvd., Saskatoon, Saskatchewan, Canada.}}

%% Follow this form:
    % \affiliation{American Meteorological Society, 
    % Boston, Massachusetts.}

\affiliation{Environment Canada,  Saskatoon, Saskatchewan, Canada.}

%% Follow this form:
    %\email{latex@ametsoc.org}

\email{bruce.davison@ec.gc.ca}

%% If appropriate, add additional authors, different affiliations:
    %\extraauthor{Extra Author}
    %\extraaffil{Affiliation, City, State/Province, Country}

\extraauthor{{Kwok Pan Chun (Sun)} and {Howard Wheater}}
\extraaffil{University of Saskatchewan, Saskatoon, Saskatchewan, Canada.}

%% May repeat for a additional authors/affiliations:

\extraauthor{Muluneh Mekonnen}
\extraaffil{Government of Alberta, Calgary, Alberta, Canada.}

\extraauthor{Vincent Fortin}
\extraaffil{Environment Canada,  Montreal, Quebec, Canada.}

\extraauthor{Robert Leconte}
\extraaffil{Universit\'{e} de Sherbrooke,  Sherbrooke, Quebec, Canada.}

\extraauthor{Anthony Liu}
\extraaffil{Environment Canada,  Edmonton, Alberta, Canada.}

\extraauthor{Tricia Stadnyk}
\extraaffil{University of Manitoba,  Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada.}
```

Comment: Please post an example code that reproduces the problem. Without this it may be impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  As @IanThompson suggested, it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  Otherwise we are just guessing at the cause and solution without any way to check that the proposed solution works for you.

Comment: The document works at the customer site but not when it runs on our system. We are both running 2013 version of the software so something must be different on our system and I'm not sure what that could be.

Comment: I found this file ametsoc2014.bst. I this the type of information you are looking for. I don't know how to upload the file.

Comment: I removed that file from the submission and the line numbers are still duplicated.

Comment: These are the lines that appear to be the problem.

Comment: @BrendaDean Take a look at PeterGrill's comment: a compilable example with `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Once you have turned the above code snippet into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces the problem, add `\listfiles` just _before_ `\begin{document}`. This will produce a list of the packages used and if you post that list here and it differs from what others have, we can determine which package is the cause of the problem.

Comment: The customer is actually using 2014. The customer worked with someone stating the we are using 4.11 of lineno.sty instead of the most up-to-date version 4.41.How do I get that version on my system since we are running 2014 the update tool goes not work.